# I cant get a basic for loop to work java 8

Tags: java

I was testing out the loops and when i try this it doesn't work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0;i==5;i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

When i run this i expect to get "0,1,2,3,4,5" but I get nothing other than "BUILD SUCCESSFUL". I'm using netbeans 8.0 on ubuntu linux. Any help or an explanation why will be appreciated.

EDIT:*facepalm

Comment: `i==5` will be false first time.

Comment: ...so the loop breaks before the first iteration, and nothing gets displayed.

Comment: In all versions of java this loop won't work

Comment: Quite funny that this one got so many downvotes. It's a problem someone has with code. It complies perfectly with SO guidelines. It shows the code, you can follow what the OP wants to do and what he did to solve the problem. You can even spot the problem directly that he can't see and that he doesn't know. In this sense, this one is a good question. Even more, it's a textbook example of a good question. It even provides expected output. And this from a new user. Is this some sort of spam?

Comment: If it's some sort of spam and downvoters know this, then they should comment. If they have another reason, they should comment also, the reason is either not obvious or it's not a good reason. Until I see a good reason to downvote, I clearly upvote here. +1

Comment: thanks and im a java noob thats why this post is here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java `for` loops, like `while` loops, you don't specify a "break", but instead a "continue" condition. Thus, you should replace the `==` with `<=`.

Answer (score 2):

The `termination expression` `i == 5` is false at starting itself in the for loop in your case.

That is why it is not going inside the loop and printing anything.

From Java Doc - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

```
When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
```

And this problem is nothing to do with java 8. Its a basic issue.

Answer (score 2):

actually it means that u
loop will be continue if i==5 but initially u declared i=0 so condition is false and for loop terminated if u want to continue than try this instead of i==5  u use i<5 or i<=5

```
 for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
for(int i=0; i<=5; i++)
```

Comment: Should explain why this would work as opposed to what OP was doing.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake inside the "for"

```
i == 5
```

however if you want use java 8 featurs and iterate on a list of integers you can do this

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);

numbers.forEach( value -> System.out.println(value));
```

in this way you can't be wrong on the <= or < or ==

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exact equivalent to your implementation it should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0;i!=5;i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

although I guess the standard approach with `i <= 5` should be preferred.